# Show spinning wheel or progressbar when website is loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a treeview with a jQuery plugin called jquery-treeview. Building up this treeview takes a lot of time (ca. 5-7 sec) and I want to show a spinning wheel or a progress bar when the page is loading. Does anyone know how to do that? I only found solutions for loading videos or images where it is known how much data has to be loaded.

Comment: Sorry to sound pedantic, but 5-7 seconds to load a website is painful for the user. Please consider an optimization, such as only building the top-level of the tree at first.

Answer (score 13):

Try this website:

http://fgnass.github.com/spin.js/

You can create a spinner of your choice and then they give examples of how to use it below.

Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Hiya see this **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/hEB7d/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/Eh8tU/ (just to show image)

Bruv , for progress bar try twitter bootstrap, **or** flick some code I might be able to see an help you out.

Idea is that code know when `on load` and `on success` will happen for your code snippet and put the image load in-between that process.

Comment: @Shikiryu cooleos, gimme 2 mins, will ping you soon! :) this is happening because the image load happens too fast see this: http://jsfiddle.net/Eh8tU/ that load image will appear before the actual image will show up :) if you add this in your code this should work, have a nice one, cheerios! p.s. I am trying to build delay in-between to show you a sample if I can :)