# How can I load a spinning icon when using xmlhttprequest object

Tags: javascript

How can I load a spinning icon when using xmlhttprequest in JavaScript while Ajax is processing and I want to direct it to an innerHTML of a tag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10409730/show-spinning-wheel-or-progressbar-when-website-is-loading. This will help

Comment: Use the keywords from your question in a search engine for starters. Come back here when you have a question concerning a specific programming problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AJAX Loading Icon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210335/ajax-loading-icon)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `'Loading...'` just use your spinner image and correct the path to `your_file.txt` to get a response from server:

```js
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var res = this.responseText;

      setTimeout(function(){
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
      }, 2000);
    } else {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 'Loading...';
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "your_file.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<div id="demo">
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>
```

You don't need the `setTimeout` either - it's just for demo purposes, so you can actually see and verify the spinner when the response comes back way to  fast, i.e. on localhost.

Comment: Thanks but the real deal is how do I replace a spinner object instead of loading.... I have a spinner but I must call a function for it to work so do I write.  InnerHTML = "<I id="spinner"><script>rotate("spinner")<\script><\i>" cause this is how I wrote mine but it never works but the same code in double quotes if it was to be placed in the body of my HTML it works fine but when I write it and save it to an innerHTML of another tag it won't work

Comment: can you post your spinner code in JSBin or somewhere to to look at?